# Find a pattern in a file and any files that file references

Tags: grep, find

Say I have a file foo.txt and I want to search for "bar", but I also want to search any files that foo.txt contains. For example:

foo.txt:

```
blah
blahblah.txt
bar
bar.txt
/user/john/baboon.txt
```

blahblah.txt:

```
monkey
bar
giraffe
```

bar.txt:

```
elephant
bar zebra
hippo
```

/user/john/baboon.txt:

```
lion
leopard
```

And it returns something like

```
foo.txt line 3: bar
foo.txt line 4: bar.txt
blahblah.txt line 2: bar
bar.txt line 2: bar zebra
```

I've played around with grep and I think I've seen something like this in action before

Comment: How do you know if a content in `foo.txt` is a file or a word?

Comment: Similar to how you can attempt to go to file (gf) in vim? I'm not sure how that works either

Answer (score 0):

If all files has suffix *.txt*:

```
grep -n bar $(grep '(.*).txt$' foo.txt) foo.txt
```